# MVC3/LINQ/EF4.1 selecting distinct col values from a result set?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

How can I select a list of column values from a result set (as distinct) and put into a list?

```
class T {int id; string name;}
```

-- Controller...

```
var query = @"exec someStoredProc";
IEnumerable<T> bb =
 db2.Database.SqlQuery<T>(query);    

// Something like???:
List<string> Names = bb.SelectDistinct("name");  // returns distinct list of names from result set
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just need the distinct list of names, you can project to the `name` property and the just use `Distinct()` :

```
List<string> Names = bb.Select( x=> x.name)
                       .Distinct()
                       .ToList();
```

This requires that you make the `name` property public, also I would rethink your class name `T`, how about `CustomerName` (or whatever else is expressive enough so you know what it means) ?

```
public class CustomerName 
{
  public int id{get;set;}
  public string name {get;set;}
}
```